# Gradle not recognizing mysql dependency

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-mvc, gradle

I am trying to move from H2 in memory database to mysql and I incorporated `compile("mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.6")` to my build.gradle after removing the H2 dependency. I also put the following in my application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mutibodb
spring.datasource.username=xxx
spring.datasource.password=xxx
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: create
```

However, when I rebuild, I get this error: http://pastebin.com/4cS9Dk0U
This is the same error I get if I don't put either mysql or h2 dependency, which means it does not take it at all.

My full existing code which was working with H2 database is here: https://github.com/devdeep1987/MutiboProject/tree/master/MutiboServer

Could you please tell me if there is a step I missed.

**Update:**
My CustomUserDetailsService class is the following:

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
private UserRepository repository;

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomUserDetailsService.class);
@Autowired
public CustomUserDetailsService(UserRepository repo) {
    this.repository = repo;
}

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String name) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    logger.info("username:"+name);

    User u = repository.findByUsername(name);
    if (u == null)
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User details not found with this username: " + name);
    String username = u.getUsername();
    String password = u.getPassword();
    List authList = new ArrayList();
    authList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER"));

    //get the encoded password
    //String encodedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(password);

    org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User user = new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(username, password, authList);

    return user;
}

public boolean createUser(String username, String password) {
    User existing = repository.findByUsername(username);
    if(existing!=null)
        return false;
    User u = new User();
    u.setUsername(username);
    u.setPassword(password);

    repository.save(u);
    return true;
}

private List getAuthorities(String role) {
    List authList = new ArrayList();
    authList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER"));

    //you can also add different roles here
    //for example, the user is also an admin of the site, then you can add ROLE_ADMIN
    //so that he can view pages that are ROLE_ADMIN specific
    if (role != null && role.trim().length() > 0) {
        if (role.equals("admin")) {
            authList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
        }
    }

    return authList;
}
}
```

and my UserRepository class is:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long>{

User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

Comment: This is your problem: `No qualifying bean of type [showcase.UserRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}`. Sow the class `CustomUserDetailsService.class` and the `UserRepository`

Comment: Ok. But it was working when I was using H2. So why would it complain now? Should I post the code of those classes here?

Comment: Yes please post this classes.

Comment: @Jens I have added the classes

Comment: @Jens If possible, could you please explain what the error says. It seems it is unable to locate the UserRepository. But then, it was able to do so when I was using the in memory database. If I revert back to H2 db then it builds.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the version of spring-boot-gradle-plugin from 1.0.2.RELEASE to 1.1.4.RELEASE fixes this. Not sure why though.